# Create an advanced variadic extension for Data in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to append Different byte storage types like `Int8, Int16, Int32, ..` into data. It has become very complex as every time I have to convert one by one to data and append the same.

How to create extension for Data which will accept `Int8, Int16, Int16 Int32` in any order and return bytes

Typically the below code should work. I tried but. not able to finish the extension method

```
let value1: Int8 = 0x01
let value2: Int16 = 0x0001
let value3: Int32 = 0x00000001

let data = Data.getBytes(value1, value2, value3)

extension Data {  
    static func getBytes(...) -> Data {
        // How to proceed?
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a common type that will be accepted by `getBytes`. Unfortunately we cannot use `FixedWidthInteger` directly, because it contains a `Self` constraint. We cannot use `FixedWidthInteger` as a generic parameter either, because then we would not be able to mix `Int8` and `Int16` and so on in a single call.

Therefore, instead of using `Any`, I would suggest to introduce a new protocol `MyIntType` and let all the types you want to support implement this:

```
protocol MyIntType {
    // ...
}

extension Int8: MyIntType { }
extension Int16: MyIntType { }
extension Int32: MyIntType { }

extension Data {  
    static func getBytes(_ values : MyIntType...) -> Data { /* ... */ }
}
```

In `getBytes`, you need to access the internal bytes from the concrete Int-Type, e.g. call something like `Data(bytes: &intValue, count: MemoryLayout<Int8>.size)`. Fortunately, `Int8` etc. support something like `bitWidth` (which is similar to the `MemoryLayout`) because the all conform to the `FixedWidthInteger` protocol.

Nevertheless, we cannot use `FixedWidthInteger` directly in the `getBytes` function, because it contains a `Self` constraint.

As a work-around, we just need to add the `bitWidth` property to our `MyIntType` protocol:

```
protocol MyIntType  {
  var bitWidth:Int { get }
}
```

All those `Int`x-Types already implement it, so we do not need an extension for them, and can simply use it in `getBytes`:

```
extension Data {  
    static func getBytes (_ values:MyIntType...) -> Data {
        var d = Data()
        for var v in values {
            let data = Data(bytes:&v, count:v.bitWidth / 8)        
            d.append(contentsOf:data)
        }
        return d
    }  
}
```

Now we can check it:

```
let value1: Int8 = 0x01
let value2: Int16 = 0x0010
let value3: Int32 = 0x00000100

let bytes = Data.getBytes(value1, value2, value3)
print (bytes)
for b in bytes {
    print (b)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but none of them is useful because they are all so self-constrained :-) And you won't get the `data` interface let each make a `Data` out of `self`

Comment: `extension FixedWidthInteger`, `Data(bytes: &int, count: self.bitWidth / 8)`

Comment: Yep, but when using it as a function argument, you get `error: protocol 'FixedWidthInteger' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` -- and this is the moment when I just kick something out.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen This code is working fine. Is there any way we can simplify this?

Comment: Yes, thanks to @Sulthan who gave the hint on what to improve. See my changed answer.